# xslt : delete spaces and CR in for each select

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, select, foreach

These days I am trying to solve a problem of code. I have an XML file that I transform with an XMLT file in a XML file solution.

XML file :

```
<invoice:detail date_begin="2017-06-23T07:38:06" date_end="2017-06-23T07:38:06">
    <invoice:diagnosis type="by_contract" code="U"/>
    <invoice:kvg reason="disease" patient_id="807528265414586413"/>
    <invoice:services>
      <invoice:record_tarmed record_id="22">
          Rapport médical
    </invoice:record_tarmed>
   </invoice:services>
</invoice:detail>
```

XSLT file :

```
<xsl:template match="invoice:request">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="invoice:invoice/invoice:detail/invoice:services/invoice:record_tarmed">
      <xsl:element name="DetailFacture">
        <nomPrestation>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </nomPrestation>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

result :

```
  <DetailFacture>
    <nomPrestation>
      Rapport médical
    </nomPrestation>
  </DetailFacture>
```

I have to pass this file to microsoft access with the transformNodeToObject method.  the text 'Rapport médical' does not appear in the field 'nomPrestation'.

If I change in the XML file

```
<invoice:record_tarmed record_id="22">Rapport médical</invoice:record_tarmed>
```

on only one line, it appears.

my question is : how to delete the spaces and CR in the select of for each ?

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. The actual question should probably be about why Access doesn't produce the desired result, and should include the code you're using to do the transform, and display the result

Comment: Indeed, provide a **full** XML, XSLT, and code to do transform and import. It seems redundant to run a `for:each` on one child node. As mentioned, right now you are presenting us with your Y solution but not explaining the X problem.

Comment: Nonetheless, look into [normalize-space](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_normalize-space.html): `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />`

Comment: I have 23 items in my for each but only one falls down. Thanks for your answer. If I use <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />, it's good but a new problem appears : MS access don't accept text with '/' in.